# I'm trying to retrieve data from a database (mySql) with Android Studio

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to retrieve data from a database. It uses a php file as well as another Java class ie. Config.java. I'm using an id which is retrieved from a previous activity using a function. The database table is called students and uses the primary key 'username'.
Here's the code for my Java class editdata:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class editdata extends AppCompatActivity {

    String id =login_students.getuidp();

    EditText fn;
    EditText db;
    EditText sm;
    EditText brnch;
    EditText gnme;
    EditText em;
    EditText gpn;
    EditText mb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editdata);



        fn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        db = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob);
        sm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sem);
        brnch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.branch);
        gnme=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.guardian_name);
        em = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        gpn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.parent_mobile);
        mb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile);



        getData();
    }
    private void getData() {

        if (id.equals("")) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Check Detail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        
        String url = Config.DATA_URL + "id";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                showJSONS(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(editdata.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    private void showJSONS(String response) {
        String name = "";
        String dob = "";
        String sem = "";
        String branch = "";
        String email = "";

        String gname="";
        String gphn = "";
        String mob = "";



        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject ob = result.getJSONObject(0);
            name = ob.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            dob = ob.getString(Config.KEY_DOB);
            gname= ob.getString(Config.KEY_GNAME);
            sem= ob.getString(Config.KEY_SEM);
            branch= ob.getString(Config.KEY_BRANCH);
            gphn= ob.getString(Config.KEY_PMOB);
            email= ob.getString(Config.KEY_EMAIL);
            mob=ob.getString(Config.KEY_MOB);




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fn.setText("" + name);
        db.setText("" + dob);
        sm.setText("" + sem);
        brnch.setText("" + branch);
        em.setText("" + email);
        gnme.setText("" + gname);
        mb.setText("" + mob);
        gpn.setText(""+ gphn);
    }
}
```

Here are the error messages:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value All of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2021-04-15 08:32:30.094 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.094 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.095 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.095 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.myapplication.editdata.showJSONS(editdata.java:101)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.096 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.myapplication.editdata.access$000(editdata.java:21)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.096 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.myapplication.editdata$1.onResponse(editdata.java:72)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.096 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.myapplication.editdata$1.onResponse(editdata.java:68)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.097 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.100 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.101 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.101 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.101 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.101 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.102 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.103 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.104 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.104 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.350 14308-14332/com.example.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b9050c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9b903210)
2021-04-15 08:32:30.599 14308-14308/com.example.myapplication I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 7052 bytes, containing 1 windows, 24 views
2021-04-15 08:32:54.075 14308-14313/com.example.myapplication I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=241KB, data=205KB
2021-04-15 08:32:54.076 14308-14313/com.example.myapplication I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=227KB, data=156KB
```

The Config file and the php file work correctly but I'm a beginner so I cant seem to figure out the issue.Please help!

Here's the Config file:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class Config {

    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://192.168.0.111/loginregister/login.php ?id=";

    public static final String KEY_NAME = "fullname";
    public static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
    public static final String KEY_DOB = "dob";
    public static final String KEY_GNAME = "guardian_name";
    public static final String KEY_SEM = "sem";
    public static final String KEY_BRANCH = "branch";
    public static final String KEY_PMOB = "parent_mobile";
    public static final String KEY_MOB = "mobile";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

Also the php file just in case:

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','loginregister');

 
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
$id  = $_GET['id'];

 
$sql = "select * from students where username like '%$id%'";
 
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 
$result = array();
 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,array('fullname'=>$row[2],'gender'=>$row[3],'dob'=>$row[4],
'guardian_name'=>$row[5],'sem'=>$row[6],'branch'=>$row[7],'parent_mobile'=>$row[8],'mobile'=>$row[9],
'email'=>$row[10]

));
}
 
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
 
mysqli_close($con);
 
?>
```

Comment: You're getting a response, but you're trying to get a field using the wrong type on line 101

Comment: @GabeSechan Can you please tell me what I should change it to?